# array is returning null and crashing

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array of objects in a class and trying to reference that array to a `UIPickerView`, but when the `UITextField` is tapped it crashes and comes back nil. When tapped on the countryInput text field it should show a pickerview with "Monaco, Japan" and so on...Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? thank you in advance.

```
class SelectionViewController: UIViewController {

var lifeArr : [LifeClass] = []

let picker = UIPickerView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()     

    let Monaco = LifeClass()
    Monaco.country = "Monaco"
    Monaco.male = 85.6
    Monaco.female = 93.5

    let Japan = LifeClass()
    Japan.country = "Japan"
    Japan.male = 81.9
    Japan.female = 88.8

    lifeArr = [Monaco, Japan]
  }

}


class SetupViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var birthDayInput: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var countryInput: UITextField!

var selectionData : SelectionViewController!
var picker = UIPickerView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

        picker.dataSource = self
        picker.delegate = self

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return selectionData.lifeArr.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return selectionData.lifeArr[row].country
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    countryInput.text = selectionData.lifeArr[row].country
}



}
```

Comment: How are these two view controllers linked? You set up the source data for the picker in one VC when the view is loaded, but use it in another VC. Why do this? You need a reference to the VC to be passed to `SetupViewController` - I'll assume this hasn't been done and is causing your null pointer error and the crash.

Comment: Where have to assigned the instance of `SelectionViewController` to `selectionData` in `SetupViewController`?

Comment: Why are you passing the whole `ViewController` reference while you just need the array. Just pass the array `lifeArr` from `SelectionViewController` to `SetupViewController`. Plus you don't need the `let picker = UIPickerView()` inside `SelectionViewController`

Comment: sorry, only been coding for a few months and still trying to learn. I thought i was referencing it with the "var selectionData : SelectionViewController!" line.

Comment: @MarkRogers what you're actually doing is declaring a reference which will be defaulted to null. Unless you give it a value at some time, it will still be null when you use it. Why is your array declared in another VC?

Comment: ok, yeah.. makes sense. the array is in another file because its a ton of code because i have every country setup to a value. i was trying to use that as my data source and reference it in the view that i was using it in to keep my code a little easier to read. Is this bad practice?

Comment: It makes sense to have it in 'another file', but probably not in another VC. Extract that code to another class and use it from both VCs (if they both need it).

Comment: thats what i was trying to achieve at first. ill continue to play with the code but once i take off the superclass UIViewController, i need to take out viewDidLoad also. once i do that everything says "Expected declaration"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new class to keep this data in and use it from whichever VCs need to access it. E.g.

```
class LifeClassDatabase
{
  var lifeArr : [LifeClass] = []

  init() 
  {
    let Monaco = LifeClass()
    Monaco.country = "Monaco"
    Monaco.male = 85.6
    Monaco.female = 93.5

    let Japan = LifeClass()
    Japan.country = "Japan"
    Japan.male = 81.9
    Japan.female = 88.8

    lifeArr = [Monaco, Japan]
  }

}
```

Instantiate this from e.g. `SetupViewController` top level:-

```
private var lifeClassDatabase = LifeClassDatabase()
```

Then use that in your datasource code, e.g.:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return lifeClassDatabase.lifeArr.count
}
```

Comment: There it is. dang, thank you Chris... thats what i was missing was the init().  just like that it fixed my issue. thank you again

Comment: so i was kinda on the right path? I just didn't now how to initialize the class without using a superclass. right? thank you again.

Comment: Ah, is that why you had a view controller? Just in order to have a class where you didn’t need a constructor? Understood. Yes, on right lines but significantly off on execution. Keep learning and it’ll come.

Comment: Yeah, that definitely makes more sense to do it like that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You just declare `selectionData` but not `instantiateViewController` that's why it's happening.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    selectionData = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SelectionViewController") as! SelectionViewController
    picker.dataSource = self
    picker.delegate = self
}
```

Comment: This is a poor solution. I disagree that you should instantiate a view controller just to get at some statically defined data. If the required VC is instantiated higher up the view chain and can be passed in to provide dynamic data then do so. If the data is as static as shown in the original question then find a way to get it to the second VC without creating view controllers (e.g. database class, or  just create it locally).

Comment: in given code, a person tries to declare the view controller for getting data like this `var selectionData : SelectionViewController!`

Comment: Yes they do. And this 'answers' the question but is a terrible solution.

Comment: I tried this solution and still showing "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value" when tapped on UITextField

Comment: You will need to replace "SelectionViewController" with the correct identifier as used in your own storyboard. And then you will also need to present the new view controller as your initialisation code is in `viewDidLoad` (or your picker will give an empty array). But, please do not follow this solution. Edit your question to tell us about the source of your data (static as shown, dynamic etc) and there will be a better way.

Comment: i did change the storyboard id. at first the view wouldn't even load. once i changed the id to the correct one it loads but then crashes exactly like before

Comment: and yes the data is static

Comment: if your data is static then please add your static array in `SetupViewController`

Comment: like this `private var lifeArr : [LifeClass] = []


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
        let Monaco = LifeClass()
    Monaco.country = "Monaco"
    Monaco.male = 85.6
    Monaco.female = 93.5

    let Japan = LifeClass()
    Japan.country = "Japan"
    Japan.male = 81.9
    Japan.female = 88.8

    lifeArr = [Monaco, Japan]
        picker.dataSource = self
        picker.delegate = self
}
`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is even a need to use a whole instance of `SelectionViewController` as a `dataSource` to `UIPickerView`.

Instead, you could've simply created the `[LifeClass]` array in `SetupViewController` and used it there itself.

```
 class SetupViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {
    private var lifeArr = [LifeClass]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.populateArray()
        picker.dataSource = self
        picker.delegate = self
    }

    private func populateArray() {
        let monaco = LifeClass()
        monaco.country = "Monaco"
        monaco.male = 85.6
        monaco.female = 93.5
        lifeArr.append(monaco)

        let japan = LifeClass()
        japan.country = "Japan"
        japan.male = 81.9
        japan.female = 88.8
        lifeArr.append(japan)
    }

    //Rest of the code...
}
```

In `UIPickerViewDataSource` and `UIPickerViewDelegate` methods, use

```
self.lifeArr
```

instead of

```
selectionData.lifeArr
```